# ALS update rules in matrix form?

Tags: machine-learning, matrix, recommender-system, matrix-decomposition

### Question

Is there a way to express the update rules of ALS (Alternating least squares):

$$
u_i = \left(\sum_{j: (i, j) \in \Omega} v_j v_j^\top + \lambda I\right)^{-1} \sum_{j: (i, j) \in \Omega} M_{ij} v_j \quad(i = 1, ..., n_2)
$$

in matrix form?

ALS is an algorithm for matrix factorization:
https://web.stanford.edu/~rezab/classes/cme323/S15/notes/lec14.pdf

#### Edit

Notations:

- $\Omega$ is the set of indices where the data matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n_1 \times n_2}$ is observed.
- We are searching for parameters $U = (u_1, \ldots, u_r) \in \mathbb{R}^{n_1 \times r}, V = (v_1, \ldots, v_r) \in \mathbb{R}^{n_2 \times r}$ such that $M \simeq U V^\top$.

  - $r \in \{1, \ldots, \min(n_1, n_2)\}$ is given.
- We are trying to do so by solving $\min \|P_{\Omega}(M - UV^\top)\|_F^2 + \lambda \|U\|_F^2 + \lambda \|V\|_F^2$.

  - $P_\Omega$ is a linear operator that sets entries with $(i, j) \not \in \Omega$ to $0$, and leaves other entries unchanged.
  - $\lambda \geq 0$ is a regularization coefficient.

Comment: Does $\Omega$ represent the indices where the matrix elements are observed? Or where they are non-zero?

Comment: Thank you for asking. $\Omega$ represents the indices where the matrix elements are observed. I've edited the post to clarify some notations.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best you can do is use majorization. You can majorize the objective function at iteration $t$ by creating a new matrix $\tilde{M}^{(t)}$ where

$$
\tilde{M}^{(t)}_{ij} = M_{ij} \text{ if } (i, j) \in \Omega, \\
\tilde{M}^{(t)}_{ij} = (u^{(t)}_{i})^\top v^{(t)}_j \text{ if } (i, j) \not \in \Omega. \\
$$

At each iteration, you will minimize $ \|\tilde{M}^{(t)} - UV^\top\|_F^2 + \lambda \|U\|_F^2 + \lambda \|V\|_F^2$, which is straightforward.

$$
(V^{(t+1)})^\top = ((U^{(t)})^\top U^{(t)} + \lambda I)^{-1} (U^{(t)})^\top \tilde{M}^{(t)}
$$

This is similar to the approach of Hastie et al. in "[Matrix Completion and Low-Rank SVD via Fast Alternating Least Squares](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume16/hastie15a/hastie15a.pdf)".

For those not familiar, [MM algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MM_algorithm) have several nice properties, including having the objective value decrease monotonically.

Comment: I'd never thought of this approach, and it is interesting. Thank you for answering.